# List database files of my android on adb

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I was trying to copy an existing database into the system database path, but i'm not sure the operation was succesful so i want to list databases of my tablet, i think they are stored in the directory /data/data/ i tried :

```
C:\>adb shell find /data -name *.db
```

But it gives me:

```
/system/bin/sh: find: not found
```

Also tried this:

```
C:\>adb -s c16076b0a607e5f shell find/data -name*.db
```

And still the same result.

I looked on here for similare cases but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as "system database path".  Databases are stored, by default, in /data/data/name_of_package/databases.  Even then, there is no restriction on the DB name - I could call it fred.flintstone if I wanted.  So, you will need to recursively search each databases subfolder and list their contents.  Even then, you will not see DBs stored in external storage, but, if you just want to see where yours is, then the recursive search will do.

Alternatively, if your phone is rooted, install Root Explorer and take a look!

Out of curiosity, given that there is no database path, where exactly did you copy your DB?

Comment: my db is in /data/data/test.tes.test/database/ what i want to do is go on that folder and make sure that the database really exists and was copied from sdcard

Comment: OK.  So find / -name name_of_your_db will find it anywhere.  find /data/data/test.tes.test/database -name name_of_your_database will search only that directory.

Comment: it still the same result, C:\>adb shell find -name *.db  ,
/system/bin/sh: find: not found

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry.  I get it now.  I've been misreading your question.  It's the "find" command that is missing.  Android does not include many binaries in /system/bin and the binaries included varies from version to version and ROM to ROM.  Try 'adb shell ls' (that's lima sierra).  Does that return a directory listing?

Comment: try adb shell ls /data/data/test.tes.test/database

Comment: i think i don't have permission (opendir failed, Permission denied) may be i have to root my tablet

Comment: Yes, you cannot view the /data directory without root.

Comment: i rooted my tablet successfully, and i installed root explorer so i can brows my system folders, and the surprise is that i found the data folder empty...

Comment: Well, you can now use "adb push" or copy to your SD card and then into the database folder.